# Can you use $inc on a model instance?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to do something like this...

```
BlogPost.findOne({name: req.params.name}).then((blog) => {

     blog.update({$inc: {likes: 1}});
     blog.save(function (err) {
                    if (err) console.log(err);
                    console.log('Success!');
                });
});
```

But every time I run my route, my code fails to increment the field as intended. 
Can you use $inc on model instances?

Comment: make sure `blog` dont return null

Comment: BlogPost doesn't return null, I wrote `console.log(blog)` it and it printed the document as intended.

Comment: Did you [look at the documentation?](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-update) Likely not since you are asking exactly what is listed there. But the pattern is not `.update()` then `.save()` since in this usage the `.update()` **REPLACES** the `.save()` and does smart things. So instead  provide the callback to `.update()` i.e `blog.update({ '$inc': { 'likes': 1 }},function(err) { ...`

Comment: But **REALLY** we want you to come to the realization that you need to break your "find" -> "tinker" -> "save" patterns and instead call the `.update()` from the `Model` i.e `BlogPost.update({name: req.params.name},{ {$inc: {likes: 1}},function(err) { ...` Now you are not pulling down data from the server that you do not need to, and simply telling the server to increment field in the matched document. It's like sending a page to the library for insertion into a book, as opposed to *"walking to the library bringing a book home, inserting a page then taking the book back to the library"*